# Unable to create HDFS admin super user

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, admin

I am trying to create HDFS Admin super user. I referred below for another super user creation.

[Creating HDFS Admin user](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.0/bk_hdfs_admin_tools/content/hdfs-encr-appendix.html)

I followed exact steps but after running

hdfs dfsadmin -report

report: Access denied for user abc. Superuser privilege is required.

Any pointer here? how should I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead use this command it works:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Create a local user ,

Add user to hdfs group or setup privileges to local user using Apache Ranger Web UI

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you aren't using kerberos you need to create a local Linux user on each Hadoop node. If you are using Kerberos/AD/LDAP then create a user there, setup Kerberos which takes a lot more effort.

Run this on each node to add a use as root/sudo;

```
useradd abc
passwd abc
usermod-aG hdfs abc
-instead of hdfs about it might be superuser.
su - hdfs
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/abc
hadoop fs -chown abc:abc
exit
su - abc
hadoop fs -ls /
```